Dropping an enum on SQL Server
I have an issue when trying to drop an enum on a table, during a Laravel migration,
I'm using SQL Server, and it creates a CHECK constraint, that I need to delete before dropping the column.
But that constraint name is partially dynamic like: CK__table__column__47FBA9D6,
What I did is to first retrieve the constraints, and then delete the CHECK one, to be able to drop the column I want.
It's working but I feel like there should be a better way to do that with Laravel.
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::table('tableName', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->enum('columnName', ['value1', 'value2'])->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        $constraints = \DB::select("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableName' AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'CHECK'");

        foreach($constraints as $constraint) {
            if(str_starts_with($constraint->CONSTRAINT_NAME, 'CK__tableName__columnName__')) {
                \DB::statement('ALTER TABLE tableName DROP CONSTRAINT ' . $constraint->CONSTRAINT_NAME);
            }
        }

        Schema::table('tableName', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('columnName');
        });
    }
};

What do you think?
Thanks.

From a quick google, enums seem to suck in laravel, so i'd go with just plain INTs or VARCHARs if i were you. Check constraints can't be the correct answer anyway, since it doesn't scale if one need to change the allowed values later.

yes in the end i think that's what i will do, i already know there will be new values down the road, and that constraint seems useless since the code will check it anyway before saving to the database
